# Applying a function to every element of one column with every element of other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cartesian-product, cross-product

How can the 2 columns A & B be concatenated using a custom function such that every element of **column A** is concatenated with every element of **column B**. Avoiding loops.

```
A  B
a  1 
b  2
c  3
d  4
```

Output:

[a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4]

Comment: `[f'{a}{b}' for a, b in itertools.product(df.A, df.B)]`

Comment: Thanks. I don't want a product instead I want to put a custom function here

Comment: Then ask for what you actually want instead of something you don't want.  Please review [ask], and create a [mcve]

Comment: @MaazKhan47 what kind of custom function you want to apply ?

Comment: A custom fuzzy match function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import product from itertools

```
from itertools import product

res = pd.DataFrame((product(df['A'],df['B'])),columns=['A',"B"])
```

res would be now this 
every value is repeated for each column

```
    A  B
0   a  1
1   a  2
2   a  3
3   a  4
4   b  1
5   b  2
6   b  3
7   b  4
8   c  1
9   c  2
10  c  3
11  c  4
12  d  1
```

Now you can do any custom function you want to apply,
As concatenation is mentioned so this is the way

```
finalList = list(res['A'].astype(str)+res['B'].astype(str))
print(finalList)
```

result:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
```

Comment: You need to wrap the product in a list
`res = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['col_1'],df['col_2'])),columns=['col_1',"col_2"])`

Comment: without applying list the results are same

Answer (score 1):

Please have look at the docs of [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get an understanding of the implementation.

edited the same as below for your need

```
def product(*args):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args]
    result = [[]]
    prods = []
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        prods.append(''.join(prod))
    return prods  


product(df['A'], df['B'].astype(str))
```

> output :
>    `['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4','c1','c2','c3','c4','d1','d2','d3','d4']`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `MultiIndex.from_product` to create of tuple cartesian products and `map` to flatten and join them

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.A, df.B]).map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format).tolist()

Out[140]:
['a1',
 'a2',
 'a3',
 'a4',
 'b1',
 'b2',
 'b3',
 'b4',
 'c1',
 'c2',
 'c3',
 'c4',
 'd1',
 'd2',
 'd3',
 'd4']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
a=['a','b','c','d','e']
b=['1','2','3','4','5']
c=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
   c.append(a[i]+b[i])

print(c)
```

Comment: it is wrong you are taking a,b as list but it is mention a,b are two columns in a dataframe